# ScrollEvent with one Item Only

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView with one Item. I want to use Scroll event on that. Means scroll event should call even one item i RecyclerView. It is possible in iOS. Is it possible in Android ?

Comment: I think it's possible in iOS because you have a bounce on UITableView/UIScrollView but RecyclerView doesn't have that, so the scroll event is not triggered

Comment: Thank Sir. I am thinking the same